# Trying to connect 3 monitors to Dell E6530

Tags: multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, displayport, dell-latitude, docking-station

For work, I had a Dell E6530 with the [e-port plus docking station](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=bsd&cs=04&sku=430-3114) (and additional shelf thing above it).  After looking up the CPU, it uses integrated HD 4000, and claims up to 3 monitors.  What I'm wondering, has anyone succeeded with this?  I tried an active displayport adapter, but it behaved like a passive adapter.  (the extra monitor would be detected, but nothing would display on it.)  perhaps I'd need something like [this](http://www.maximumpc.com/evgas_displayport_hub_lets_you_string_together_three_monitors_single_source2013)?  or would i be best off just using a usb to dvi/vga adapter?

Answer (score 0):

In the BIOS makes sure that the NVidia Optimus setting is enabled.

Comment: Where in the BIOS? I have the same Dell, and I don't see that option.